# Find the value $\hat{\beta}$ which minimizes $\sum_{i=1}^{4}|i||i- \beta|$ for $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics, inequality, optimization

I am looking for the value $\hat{\beta}$ which satisfies the following condition: for each $\beta \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4}|i||i - \hat{\beta}| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{4}|i||i - \beta|\text{.}$$
Simulation confirms that $\hat{\beta} = 3$ works as a solution:

```
f <- function(beta) {
  i <- seq(1, 4, 1)
  return(sum(abs(i)*abs(i- beta)))
}
optimize(f, interval = c(-10, 10))
$minimum
[1] 3.000031
```

However, I'm not sure how to arrive at the answer of $3$ through theoretical machinery.

I had attempted to handwave this by saying that it is sufficient, by term-by-term comparison, to compare $|i - \hat{\beta}|$ to $|i - \beta|$, for which $\hat{\beta}$ should be the median of $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, yielding an answer of $2.5$ (which is not supported by simulation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case: the function is linear on each of the intervals $[-\infty, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, \infty]$. Thus, if it achieves a minimum it will do so at one of the integers $1, 2, 3, 4$. You can check four cases by hand.

You can further reduce your choices by noting that $\beta$ being far from $3$ or $4$ is "punished more harshly" than being far from 1 or 2, so in fact the minimum will be at 3 or 4.

Answer (score 2):

The right part, after division by $10$, can be viewed as expectation of absolute difference of random variable $i$ and constant $\beta$, but with not uniform distribution on $i$ (we have $P(i = k) = \frac{i}{10}$). Such sum is minimized by taking $\beta$ equal to median of the distribution - or, in discrete case, when exact median doesn't exist, minimizing $|P(i > \beta) - P(i < \beta)|$.